# Vbs Multiplication Table

Tags: vbscript

i was making resource for my programming class well its actually very basic scripting and i found this site and look through it there was realy many useful stuff about scripting but the thing i was searching for wasnt on the list or i wasnt using right keyword
anyway my question is 
My teacher ask me to write a Vbs to Print Multiplication Table and i made researches and this is where i am right now;

```
dim sum, arraynum(), arrayline1, count, arraynum2(), arrayline2, arraynum3(), arrayline3, arraynum4(), arrayline4, arraynum5(), arrayline5

count=1
sum=1
arrayline1=1

for count=1 to 5
    redim preserve arraynum(arrayline1)
    redim preserve arraynum2(arrayline2)
    redim preserve arraynum3(arrayline3)
    redim preserve arraynum4(arrayline4)
    redim preserve arraynum5(arrayline5)
    arraynum(arrayline1)=sum
    arraynum2(arrayline2)=sum*2
    arrayline2=arrayline2+1
    arraynum3(arrayline3)=sum*3
    arrayline3=arrayline3+1
    arraynum4(arrayline4)=sum*4
    arrayline4=arrayline3+1
    arraynum5(arrayline5)=sum*5
    arrayline5=arrayline5+1
    sum=sum+1
    arrayline1=arrayline1+1
next

wscript.echo join(arraynum) & vbcrlf & join(arraynum2) & vbcrlf & join(arraynum3) & vbcrlf & join
(arraynum4) & vbcrlf & join(arraynum5)

' Its printing like;
'   1 2 3 4 5
'   2 4 6 8 10
'   3 6 8 12 15
'   4 8 12 16 20
'   5 10 15 20 25
```

as you can see they are not in a straight line and i wasnt able to do this with an input i mean take an input and show multiplication table for that i hope i made myself clear enough and if its not too much to ask how can i put a border between them or is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to apply leftpadding to your values that you are printing: Count the number of characters that a value contains, substract them from a fixed amount and add the same amount of spaces to the value. 
This is an example that will replace and leftpad the `vbTab` character. If you `join` your arrays with a `vbTab` instead of the default space, you can use such a function.

Because this is a homework assignment, I added also some code that recursively get the multiples for a number, starting with 0. Just to trigger some curiosity. I would not recommend to just copy paste it, it does not comply to your requirement: "start from 1".

```
dim multiple

' Get the numbers 0 to 5
for each multiple in split(getMultiples(1,5), vbTab)
    ' print the multiplication table for each of this numbers
    wscript.echo trim(TabToLpad(getMultiples(multiple, 5), 10))
next

' Does the calculation and returns a Tab delimited string of all multiples
function getMultiples(nr, amount)
    getMultiples = 0
     ' As long as the amount is larger then 0, get the next multiple
    if amount > getMultiples then getMultiples = getMultiples(nr, amount-1) & vbTab & (nr * amount)
End function

' Pads each value in a tab delimited string with the nrPadChars spaces. Returns a string.
function tabToLpad(str, nrPadChars)
    dim part
    for each part in split(str, vbTab)
        tabToLpad = tabToLpad & string(nrPadChars - len(part), " ") & part
    next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @AutomatedChaos
No I will not copy paste it but instead try to improve my script. I made some more research and i am realy close now but still there is something wrong i cant make a straight line I tried to do left padding but each time its throwing an error this is where i am right now
` Dim MaxNum
Dim x, y, sum2, sum
MaxNum=inputbox("Please Enter Multiplier Range:")
x=1
y=1
sum2=1
For y = 1 To MaxNum
  For x = 1 To MaxNum
  redim preserve arraynum(sum2)
  arraynum(sum2)=sum
  sum2=sum2+1
  sum=x * y
  Next
Next
Wscript.Echo join(arraynum, Chr(5) & VBtab)`